# Problem trying to implement 'Game of Life' in python as a beginner

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, conways-game-of-life

So I am an absolute beginner in python and tried my hand at implementing Conway's game of life.
I am not using any libraries at all, my grid is just a 50x50 matrix of 1s and 0s.
The next_gen output I get is not matching the expected output but I couldn't figure out why, any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
def alive_neighbours(grid, r, c):
    count = 0
    if grid[r-1][c-1] == 1:
        count += 1
    if grid[r-1][c] == 1:
        count += 1
    if grid[r-1][c+1] == 1:
        count += 1
    if grid[r][c-1] == 1:
        count += 1
    if grid[r][c+1] == 1:
        count += 1
    if grid[r+1][c-1] == 1:
        count += 1
    if grid[r+1][c] == 1:
        count += 1
    if grid[r+1][c+1] == 1:
        count += 1
    return count


grid = [[0 for i in range(50)] for j in range(50)]
grid[25][25] = 1
grid[26][26] = 1
grid[27][24] = 1
grid[27][25] = 1
grid[27][26] = 1
grid[49][49] = 1


def next_gen(grid):
    new_grid = grid[:]
    for r in range(1, 49):
        for c in range(1, 49):
            neighbour = alive_neighbours(grid, r, c)
            if (r == 0 or c == 0) or (r == 49 or c == 49):
                pass                                # I am yet to define edge case
            else:
                if grid[r][c] == 1 and (neighbour > 3 or neighbour < 2):
                    new_grid[r][c] = 0
                    continue
                elif grid[r][c] == 1 and (neighbour == 2 or 3):
                    continue
                elif grid[r][c] == 0 and neighbour == 3:
                    new_grid[r][c] = 1
                    continue
                else:
                    continue
    grid = new_grid[:]


def printf(grid):
    for r in range(50):
        for c in range(50):
            if grid[r][c] == 1:
                print("*", end=" ")
            else:
                print(" ", end=" ")
        print("")


x = 0
while x != '-1':
    x = (input("x: "))
    printf(grid)
    next_gen(grid)
```

I also tried rewriting my next_gen function, but using that there is absolutely no change in the matrix

next_gen:

```
def next_gen(grid):
    new_grid = grid[:]
    for r in range(1, 49):
        for c in range(1, 49):
            neighbour = alive_neighbours(grid, r, c)
            if (r == 0 or c == 0) or (r == 49 or c == 49):
                pass
            else:
                if grid[r][c] == 1 and neighbour == 2 or 3:
                    continue
                if grid[r][c] == 0 and neighbour == 3:
                    new_grid[r][c] = 1
                    continue
                if grid[r][c] == 1:
                    new_grid[r][c] = 0
                continue
    grid = new_grid[:]
```

Comment: Which part is not matching/incomplete about the nextgen matrix?

Comment: The second implementation never assigns the new_grid to the current/old one so of course nothing changes :). Also there is no need for all the continues inside proper if/else clauses, if/elif/else pattern already guarantees at most one path is taken

Comment: the second implementation does do that, forgot to copy paste properly here, editing now

Comment: as @Eric says you never actually update the value of grid thats used for printing, you only update the local grid scoped variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As bruno said in his answer there are a few issues in your code, He already told about your issue with grid and how allocating to it in the function actually points the local scope version to the new grid and not the global scope one. He also covers how to resolve this.

The other issue you will have is that you have undertood that just doing `new_grid = grid` will mean that new_grid and grid point at the same list. So to prevent this you have correctly done `new_grid = grid[:]` as this will create a new list in memory and copy the data from the grid list. However thats a shallow copy, so you will create a new list object but copy all the list references inside your list. we can demonstrate this by doing a shallow copy of a list and then changing a value in the new list.

```py
grid_size = 2
grid = [[0 for i in range(grid_size)] for j in range(grid_size)]
new_grid = grid[:]
new_grid[1][1] = "R"
print("grid:", grid)
print("newg:", new_grid)

#output#
grid: [[0, 0], [0, 'R']]
newg: [[0, 0], [0, 'R']]
```

So you can see that changing the inner list in one will change the inner list in the other. so you need to do a deep copy of the list so that your not changing the original grid as you go. Since conways states are based on the original grid state and squares changing shouldnt impact the others. I think your already aware of this concept.

I also made a change to the alive neighbours to simplyfy it. Below is a quick draft adaptation. when you run it you should see your glider heading off to the bottom right corner

```py
from copy import deepcopy


def alive_neighbours(grid, r, c):
    differences = (0, -1, +1)
    cells_in_square = [(r + a, c + b) for a in differences for b in differences]
    total = 0
    for x,y in cells_in_square[1:]:
        try:
            if x >=0 and y>=0:
                total += grid[x][y]
        except IndexError as ie:
            pass #ignore index errors as at the edge of the grid
    return total


def next_gen(grid):
    new_grid = deepcopy(grid)
    for r in range(len(grid)):
        for c in range(len(grid)):
            neighbour = alive_neighbours(grid, r, c)
            if grid[r][c] == 1 and (neighbour > 3 or neighbour < 2):
                new_grid[r][c] = 0
            elif grid[r][c] == 0 and neighbour == 3:
                new_grid[r][c] = 1
    return new_grid


def printf(grid):
    for r in grid:
        for c in r:
            if c == 1:
                print("*", end=" ")
            else:
                print(" ", end=" ")
        print("")


grid_size = 50
grid = [[0 for i in range(grid_size)] for j in range(grid_size)]
grid[25][25] = 1
grid[26][26] = 1
grid[27][24] = 1
grid[27][25] = 1
grid[27][26] = 1
grid[49][49] = 1

while True:
    x = (input("press enter to see next grid: "))
    if x:
        break
    printf(grid)
    grid = next_gen(grid)
```

**UPDATE**

other then the glider you started with the below is a nice start for a cool exploder

```py
grid_size = 50
grid = [[0 for i in range(grid_size)] for j in range(grid_size)]
grid[25][25] = 1
grid[26][24] = 1
grid[26][25] = 1
grid[26][26] = 1
grid[27][24] = 1
grid[27][26] = 1
grid[28][25] = 1
```

Comment: Duh ! I missed the fact it was a matrix, well done Sir !

Comment: yeah like you said there were quite a few issues in the code. I opted to ignore the `neighbours == 2 or 3` since it was a useless statement since all it done was `pass` so i just dropped it but good that you pointed it out to the OP for future reference.

Comment: Thank you, this works. I did realize that the conway states were indeed based on the original grid, but as you pointed out I had no idea about the shallow_copy and deep_copy concept. Well, atleast I learned something new. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

There are actually quite a few issues with your code, but the first and main problem is with your updated grid never being returned to the caller.

Here:

```
def next_gen(grid):
    new_grid = grid[:]
    # ...
    # code modifying new_grid
    # ...
    grid = new_grid[:]
```

within the function, `grid` is a local name. Rebinding this name at the end of the function only affects the local name, it doesn't do anything to the global one. you should [read this reference article for more in-depth explanations](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

What you want is to return the grid to the caller instead:

```
def next_gen(grid):
    new_grid = grid[:]
    # ...
    # code modifying new_grid
    # ...
    # return the new grid to the caller
    return new_grid

x = 0
while x != '-1':
    x = (input("x: "))
    printf(grid)
    # replace previous grid with the new one
    grid = next_gen(grid)
```

For some other issues, this:

```
if grid[r][c] == 1 and neighbour == 2 or 3:
```

doesn't do what you think it does.

The `neighbour == 2 or 3` part is actually executed as `(neighbour == 2) or 3`. Now the `or` operator returns either the first of it's operands that is not false, or the last of it's operand. Note that "that is not false" means "that does not have a false value in a boolean context" (all Python objects have a "truth" value, and for numbers, all numbers are true expect for zeros). So in the end, if the `neighbours` is different from `2`, the value of neighbour == 2 or 3`is`3`, whatever the value of`neighbour`:

```
>>> foo
1
>>> foo == 1 or 3
True
>>> foo == 2 or 3
3
>>>
```

And since `3` is true, the expression will have a true value even if `neighbours` is actually 1 or 4 or 5 or etc...

TL;DR: you want either:

```
`neighbour == 2 or neighbour == 3`
```

or more simply:

```
`neighbour in (2, 3)`
```

Comment: damn, i should've checked the scope of the variable, simple mistake.
Also, I had no idea about that or statement, back to basics for me. Thanks.